# how to swiftly load 150 static ImageIcon Objects of apprx. 1KB each

Tags: java, swing, java-6

I have around 150 gifs (all rather small = 1KB) in a static class and in statements like these

```
public final static ImageIcon I_ADDFAV = new ImageIcon("icons/addfavorite.gif");
public final static ImageIcon I_AUTO_LOAD = new ImageIcon("icons/auto_load.gif");
...
```

I use them to display JButtons with icons.
During Application start I noticed an increased loading time associated to these statements of approximately 2seconds. I would like to know if somebody knows a faster way to load these gifs. I was thinking that boundly all of them in a single file could be a way as I suspect that reading 150 small files from disc is the actual delay in this. But I could be wrong. Does anybody have a smart idea or has ever handled such situation? We would like to bring this down to msecs.

cheers
ioannis

Comment: Bring them in using a single file. If that does not work, read them lazily, starting with the buttons that are on the screen already, and gradually filling in the rest of them using a background thread. The important thing is not how fast your application really loads, but how fast *your users perceive* that it loads.

Comment: I wonder if you might be able to parallelize some of this loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend combining all the images into a single file, much as [a website should combine all its image requests into a single request for a bunch of sprites](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html).  Almost all of the time spent loading a file from disk is spent in seek time (moving the head to the right track on the disk) and rotational delay (waiting for the disk to rotate around so the head is over the right bits).  So, the time to read a large file from disk is essentially the same as the time to read a lot of small files from disk, and once the large image is in memory you can pull apart all the sprites and show them on your buttons.

Answer (score 1):

A common trick is to use a tile image, so that you hit the disk only once. An example of this is the image [Google](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrWWN.png) (or indeed [Stack Overflow](http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png?v=5)) uses for this purpose. In a web app, the individual icons are sliced and diced using CSS background properties (and the image itself is served using a far-future cache expiry).

In Java, one approach you might use is to use the [`getSubImage(int,int,int,int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getSubimage%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) method of `BufferedImage` to extract all the individual icons with quick, in-memory access and then create `ImageIcon`s of those and put them on your buttons.

Comment: using getsubImage sounds like the way to go. could you drop me a couple of lines as to how I can boundle the separate GIFs on disc into a single BufferedImage.

Comment: It seems to be tricky to place 150 images into a raster and then determine the exact Rectangles to obtain each individual subimage. Or is there a trick I could use ?

Comment: Easiest way is if they're all the same size, e.g. 32x32 pixels. Just put them all side-by-side in a single image (150x32)x32 pixels in size. Put a list of images in your program code and just multiply the index of the desired image in the list by 32 to get the x-coordinate of the slice you need to make. If an image of that width is impractical, put a fixed number of images on a line do a modulo division by the line length before you make the slice (and increment the y index accordingly).

Answer (score 0):

I would like to answer this question.
I have used the ideas above and have decreased loading time to milliseconds.
For the benefit of the interested readers:

1) I sorted all my GIFs. 
2) I concatenated them using copy /B into a single GIF
3) I used an editor to mark the start of each of the GIFs within the consolidated file
4) I loaded the file using RandomAccessFile.readFully and read the bytes of each of the files
5) I then used ImageIcon(bytes) to associated the application's icons to the bytes read.

Final result was more than satisfactorily in terms of performance.

Thanks